# Vertically centering a <ul> menu on a HTML page

Tags: css, html, html-lists

I have very little CSS experience, so this is probably a very elementary question. I am having problems vertically centering a `<ul>` menu in the middle of the page. I've tried the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            div {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                display: table;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                border: 10pt solid black;
            }
            ul {
                display: block;
            }
            ul li {
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: yellow;
                border: 1pt solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>item 1</li>
                <li>item 2</li>
                <li>item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want? Its working.

Comment: @Prakash - The `<ul>` menu is not vertically centered, it's displaying at the top of the page (tested in Chrome and Firefox).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to vertically center your menu do it like this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fCMuB/)

CSS

```
ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px; /* 1/2 of the total height of your ul */
}
```

And if you want your `ul` to be in very center of the page do it like this

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fCMuB/1/)

CSS

```
ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px; /* 1/2 of the total height of your ul */
    margin-left: -50px; /* 1/2 of the total width of your ul assumed here as -50 */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. However the number of element in the menu may change, so I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require a fixed menu width.